# Trying to use "Socket.io-client" module in React throws error: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, socket.io

I'm using [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) in my React js web app. It compiles without error, but when I try to open the development server (localhost:3000) I get the following error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

**In *this* project where the error is being thrown**, here is a list of the relevant packages and their versions:

- @testing-library/jest-dom@5.14.1
- @testing-library/react@11.2.7
- @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3
- react-dom@17.0.2
- react-scripts@4.0.3
- react@17.0.2
- socket.io-client@4.3.1

Webpack Version: 4.44.2

---

Threads like [this one](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039) suggest that this is some sort of issue with mixing import and module.exports in ES6, but I definitely don't want to modify the socket.io-client module.

**In a *previous React project*, where the module works**, here is a list of the relevant packages and their versions:

- @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
- @testing-library/react@9.5.0
- @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
- react-scripts@3.4.4
- react@16.14.0
- socket.io-client@4.1.2

Webpack Version: 4.42.0

I've played around a little bit with different versions of socket.io-client and react to try to get it working, but to no avail...

Comment: Downgrade socket.io-client to v4.2.0 for now. The bugs introduced due to ESM builds are being resolved. It may take up to 2-3 days for the latest version to become stable enough to use.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack uses ES syntax, so commonJS syntax will not work.

```
export default lookup
```

Comment: Is there any way around this without modifying the package itself? Because as I mentioned in the question, I've had this working before in a previous React project

Comment: You could try changing the version of webpack